# Как узнать что пользователь авторизовался в PrivateChannel в Laravel Broadcasting + laravel-echo?

Tags: php, laravel, chat, broadcasting

Привет. Ситуация такая:
Я делаю чат, где пользователи в основном будут не авторизованными на сайте (что то вроде чата техподдержки). В этом чате сообщения от бота должны приходить только тому, кто отправил вопрос. Для этого я решил использовать `Laravel 5.3 Event Broadcasting`, и использовать `PrivateChannel` вида `Chat.*`, где маска `*` - это id пользователя с которым ведется беседа.
Но чтобы авторизоваться в `PrivateChannel`, как я понял, надо быть залогиненым на сайте. Поэтому я в параметрах laravel-echo я указал `authEndpoint: '/pusher/auth'`, где запоминаю гостя в базе данных по геолокации, временной зоне и т.д.
Вот контроллер для `'/pusher/auth'`:

```
class PusherController extends Controller
{
    protected $pusher;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pusher = new \Pusher(env('PUSHER_KEY'), env('PUSHER_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID'), [
            'cluster' => 'eu',
            'encrypted' => true,
        ]);
    }

    public function auth(Request $request)
    {
         $user = $this->createChatUser($this->clientIP(), $request);

         $custom_data = json_encode($user->toArray());

         return $this->pusher->socket_auth($request->channel_name, $request->socket_id, $custom_data);
    }
}
```

После того как гость был сохранен и получил свой `id` я столкнулся с проблемой, как передать в `js` информацию, что гость был сохранен и теперь в `js` можно подписаться на канал типа `Chat.*` с помощью присвоенного ему (пользователю) `id`

```
Echo.private('Chat.' + user.id)
    .listen('MessageWasSended', (e) => {
        // ...
    })
```

Ведь в js пока не существует `user`. Тогда я решил создать на бэке событие `App\Events\ChatUserDetected` чтобы сигнализировать о том что гость был сохранен как пользователь, и передать его на фронт:

```
class ChatUserDetected implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
         return new PrivateChannel('Chat');
    }
}
```

Но теперь становится не понятно, в каком месте этот `ChatUserDetected` бродкастить, и вообще я полез в какие-то дебри. Наверняка есть легкий и красивый способ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в общих чертах, как мне после авторизации канала, которая происходит в `authEndpoint: '/pusher/auth'` передать пользователя в `js` для `laravel-echo`. Возможно и скорее всего, вообще нужно по другому это все делать.

Спасибо.